# How to find points on a circle to define a ratio-based rectangle that maximizes the space?

Tags: android, trigonometry, adaptive-icon

My question comes from the Android 8.0 Adaptive Icon requirements:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

I am working on an Android app where the launcher icon will be unknown and the people doing deployments of the app have no idea what SVG is (and no one will have the time, money, or patience to try to explain/understand what SVG is either).  This means PNG images will be *required* to look good on Android 8.0 and later.

An adaptive icon is shown at 108dp x 108dp.  On xxxhdpi (4x), it works out to a total space of 432x432 pixels.  However, only a 66dp diameter circle is used in the foreground, which is 264x264 pixels on xxxhdpi.  The problem is that the icon is inside a circle mask.  Explaining what a circle mask is and why it is required is also going to be extremely difficult.  In short, images received will be rectangular and most people like to fill in available space.

So what I want to do is take whatever rectangular input image I get and calculate its ratio (easy), but then find the rectangle of the same ratio that maximizes the space in a constrained circle with a diameter of 66dp.  I could use an Euler's method approach by going from 0 to 90 degrees (i.e. guess) until I get "close enough" but a nice, easy to follow bit of code that doesn't use a for-loop that goes directly from a ratio to a precise rectangle would be much cleaner. I prefer C/C++-style but I'll take whatever I can get as long as it is readable.  I'm quite rusty on my trigonometry - it's been almost 20 years since I last had to do any serious math so please no formulae in LaTeX without converting it to something I do understand (i.e. code) - I'm quite lost whenever I land on the math SE site these days.

(If anyone thinks I'm looking for a handout, I'm perfectly fine with doing my own work as long as I know what to look for.  I've got three unknowns:  The angle, the length of the opposite, AND the length of the adjacent.  Classic SOH-CAH-TOA doesn't directly apply.  I've got two knowns:  The length of the hypotenuse and a ratio of a rectangle.  I can hack a solution together but I'd rather not if there's a cleaner solution.)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this way too hard.  A better solution is to calculate the radius of a circle that will contain the rectangle of the original image and then scale the image based on the ratio of the source diameter to the destination diameter.  Example pseudocode:

```
w = 720
h = 405
dp = 66

halfwidth = w / 2
halfheight = h / 2
origdiameter = sqrt(halfwidth * halfwidth + halfheight * halfheight) * 2
destdiameter = dp * 4

newwidth = w * destdiameter / origdiameter
newheight = h * destdiameter / origdiameter
```

Produces 230.09 x 129.43 and will fit perfectly in the 264 pixel diameter circle.  Both rectangles are also ~16:9 (1.77777).  I may shave off a couple of dp's so that I don't have to worry about anti-aliasing chopping off pixels.  As an added bonus, doing so makes the images a nice neat 256 x 256.